# Relative links/partial routes with routerLink

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In my app some URLs take the form

```
/department/:dep/employee/:emp/contacts
```

In my sidebar I show a list of all employees, each of which has a `[routerLink]` which links to that employee's contacts

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a [routerLink]="['/department', 1, 'employee', 1, 'contacts']"></a>
    <li>
    <li>
        <a [routerLink]="['/department', 1, 'employee', 2, 'contacts']"></a>
    <li>
    ...
</ul>
```

However, with this approach I always need to provide the full path, including all the params (like `dep` in the above example) which is quite cumbersome. Is there a way to provide just part of the route, such as

```
<a [routerLink]="['employee', 2, 'contacts']"></a>
```

(without the `department` part, because I don't really care about `department` in that view and my feeling is that this goes against separation of concerns anyway)?

Comment: This is a nice answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44865817/11725783

Answer (score 88):

That's supposed to work. The leading `/` makes it an absolute route, without it (or with `./`), it becomes a relative route relative to the current route. You can also use `../` (or `../../` or more) to route relative to the parent or parents parent.

Comment: Neither with `./` nor without it do relative `routerLink`s work. They work once after page load, but if the parent component changes its part of the URL the `href` generated for the component with the relative `routerLink` is not updated and stays on the previous route. See my repo at https://github.com/erasethis/angular2-routing

Comment: I guess that needs Plunker to reproduce and investigate https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/quickstart/ts/plnkr.html Do you have a `<base href="/">` as first element inside `<head>`?

Comment: I think it's relative to the route of the component in which `routerLink` is defined. If I've actived a `/parent/child/grandchild1` route and `routerLink` is defined in the `/parent` component (which contains the sidebar for OP), then a link to `grandchild2` would still expect `routerLink` to include `child`, eg. `[routerLink]="[child, grandchild2]"`.

Comment: Can confirm. `./` does work and loads child component wrt current route.

Comment: @pbarranis "it simply isn't working"—without more details I can't help you. If your issue is different than OPs, try to reproduce in a stackblitz and post your own question

Comment: Old question/answer, but I don't see anything mentioned in here about the base url which the router would need.

Comment: @Jacques I don't see why that would be related

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer doesn't the router base relative paths off the base URL?

Comment: @Jacques relative routes are based on the current route, similar to the current working directory. `../sibling`, `../../uncle/cousin`, `child`. Absolute routes are based on base URL.

Answer (score 16):

Instead of using './' or '../', I would suggest using **relativeTo** param in router.navigate function. E.g.:

```
this.router.navigate(['child'], {relativeTo: this.route});
```

or

```
this.router.navigate(['sibling'], {relativeTo: this.route.parent});
```

Answer (score 14):

In case your `app-routing.module.ts` looks similar to this:

```js
  {
    path: '/department/:dep', component: DepartmentComponent, children: [
      { path: 'employee/:emp/contacts', component: EmployeeComponent },
      // ... Other child routes
    ]
  }
```

Assuming you are on the parent route `http://localhost:4200/department/1`, now the below `routerLinks` will work as mentioned:

1. Prefix `./` represents *relative path* from current route
2. No Prefix represents *relative path* from current route
3. Prefix `/` represents *absolute path* from root route
4. Prefix `../` represents *relative path* to move up one level from current route

```html
<ul>

  <!-- will generate URL: http://localhost:4200/department/1/employee/1/contacts-->
  <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" routerLink="recipes" routerLink="./employee/1/contacts">Relative Link that Works!:)</a>
  </li>

  <!-- is same as above and generated URL: http://localhost:4200/department/1/employee/1/contacts-->
  <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" routerLink="recipes" routerLink="employee/1/contacts">Relative Link that Works!:)</a>
  </li>

  <!-- is same as above and generated URL: http://localhost:4200/department/1/employee/1/contacts-->
  <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" routerLink="recipes" [routerLink]="['employee', '1', 'contacts']">Relative Link that Works! :)</a>
  </li>

  <!-- is NOT THE SAME as above  and generated URL: http://localhost:4200/department/employee/1/contacts-->
  <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" routerLink="recipes" routerLink="../employee/1/contacts">Relative Link that does NOT work! :( </a>
  </li>

  <!-- is NOT THE SAME as above  and generated URL: http://localhost:4200/employee/1/contacts-->
  <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" routerLink="recipes" routerLink="/employee/1/contacts">Absolute Link that does NOT work! :( </a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 11):

As described also in the official Angular doc [here](https://angular.io/guide/router#specifying-a-relative-route)
*View*

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a (click)="onViewDetails(id)">Details</a>
    <li>
    ...
```

*Component*

```
construct( private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute ){
}
onViewDetails(id){
 this.router.navigate([id], {relativeTo: this.route});
}
```

> /employee 
> /employee/:id

Comment: @adamdport which version of Angular are you refering? Angular has changed a lot since my answer :D you can check the official docs for more info on the router..thnx

Comment: @user776686 Angular being a SPA it does not have a "way" of "open in a new tab" but you can achieve it easily with window object of JS. Check this code:
```
let newRelativeUrl = router.createUrlTree([id], {relativeTo: this.route});
let baseUrl = window.location.href.replace(router.url, '');
window.open(baseUrl + newRelativeUrl, '_blank');
```
I did not test it but should work in theory.