# Send data through routing paths in Angular

Tags: angular, routes, angular-router

Is there anyway to send data as parameter with router.navigate? 
I mean, something like [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/tUe5fb?p=preview) example, as you can see the route has a data parameter, but doing this it's not working:

```
this.router.navigate(["heroes"], {some-data: "othrData"})
```

because some-data is not a valid parameter. How can I do that? I don't want to send the parameter with queryParams.

Comment: I think it should be other way like in AngularJS, where we were able to do something like $state.go('heroes', {some-data: "otherData"})

Comment: Use my approach https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-navigation-with-data last comment by me, best for everyone

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69420764/7186739

Comment: Routing is a complex feature in Angular and definitely worth learning! Here you may find interesting details about passing data via the routing:
https://indepth.dev/tutorials/angular/indepth-guide-to-passing-data-via-routing
This guide goes through various techniques about using static data in routing definition and dynamic data (state) during specific navigation.

Answer (score 900, accepted):

There is a lot of confusion on this topic because there are so many different ways to do it.

Here are the appropriate types used in the following screen shots:

```
private route: ActivatedRoute
private router: Router
```

1) Required Routing Parameters:

[image]

2) Route Optional Parameters:

[image]

3) Route Query Parameters:

[image]

4) You can use a service to pass data from one component to another without using route parameters at all.

For an example see: https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/build-a-simple-angular-service-to-share-data/

I have a plunker of this here: https://plnkr.co/edit/KT4JLmpcwGBM2xdZQeI9?p=preview

Comment: thank you for your answer! What is the difference between the 2) and the 3)? Because both end up adding "?parameter=" in the URL. Could you give me an example for the 4)? I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: I updated by answer to show the different URLs and to provide a link to a blog post and plunker on how to pass data with a service. The URL is different with optional and query parameters as shown above. Plus query parameters can be retained across routes.

Comment: I also have a Pluralsight course on routing that covers all of this: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-routing/table-of-contents You can sign up for a free week if you are interested in more information.

Comment: Thank you! I think I will do it with the service just because I don't want to show the parameters, but in some cases the other uses might work

Comment: @DeborahK, I think there is a small mistake in the photo that show how to pass query parameters. It should be `this.router.navigate(['/products'], {queryParams: {filterBy: 'x', showImage: true}});`

Comment: You are correct @Egel. I'll update the screen shots.

Comment: passing data through shared service doesn't work if the page is refreshed. the data gets undefined

Comment: It does if you register the service in a module, NOT in a component. I have an example that demonstrates it here: https://github.com/DeborahK/MovieHunter

Comment: Also worth noting that option 2 tries to serialize everything to the url, so some complex objects are lost (I had an object array get turned into `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`). It seems a service is your only choice in this case.

Comment: This seems really stupid on Angular's part. Sometimes developers want to display a message to their user when they change paths. Putting the message in the URL could lead to all sorts of hacks and social engineering opportunities

Comment: That's why they provided Option #4. :-) You can always build a service to retain any values you need. Any component can inject and access those values throughout the application. And then it is not on the URL.

Comment: is there any way to hide parameters

Comment: @DeborahK Could you explain shortly why a Shared Service wouldn't be re instantiated upon page a refresh ? I thought the only way around this was using local storage ? I ran your code, but the data is not really 'shared' as the component refetches data upon refresh, via an http call - If I am not mistaken.

Comment: The data is only "shared" within the executing application. If the user refreshes the page, the entire application is reloaded from the server, so no prior state is retained in the application. Thinking about it in terms of a normal application, when a user refreshes it is like closing and reopening the application. If you need to retain state after a refresh, then you will need to store it somewhere such as local storage or on the server.

Comment: Just a small hint: `route` type is  `ActivatedRoute`, not `Router`.

Comment: Are you referring to me? I'm curious as to why you would think that?

Comment: Thank you! I wish the official docs had clear examples like this.

Comment: Don't use screenshots on SO! This is why!

Comment: Dear @DeborahK, your Plnkr example is not working because of npm installment is failed in there. Can you please fix and let me know it works all correct?

Comment: Try this instead: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-Routing @LuDeveloper

Comment: As the accepted answer it should be nice if you'd add @Véger Lóránd his answer considering a fifth method using state.

Comment: Is that how this is supposed to work? I should be wrapping anyone else's great answers into mine?

Comment: In option 4 how can I send a method? I am getting DataCloneError

Comment: Could you elaborate on your scenario? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm getting this error on implementing method 2 - ```Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'movies;title=ring'```.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks for sharing @DeborahK

Answer (score 499):

There is a new method what came with Angular 7.2.0

https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#state

Send:

```js
    this.router.navigate(['action-selection'], { state: { example: 'bar' } });
```

Receive:

```js
    constructor(private router: Router) {
      console.log(this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.example); // should log out 'bar'
    }
```

You can find some additional info here:

https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/27198

The link above contains this example which can be useful:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bupuzn

Comment: This is the correct answer given the new features in Angular 7.

Comment: With this approach, how would I handle a browser refresh by the user? In that case the data in the navigation extras seems to go away, so there is no chance to use it again on refresh.

Comment: @tobi_b I think you are right, after refresh you can not reach it. If you need it after refresh, methods in the accepted answer will be better.

Comment: ProTip:  See the stackblitz in the answer to get this to work.

Comment: Reading the pull for this, it isn't clear to me that this is intended to replace the paramMap method, From the pull author:

getCurrentNavigation() will return the currently executing navigation. It will return null if there is no currently executing navigation (in other words, the application is in a stable state).

Comment: Yep that is why you only can get the data from the this.router.getCurrentNavigation() in the constructor.
If you need it elsewhere like inside ngOnInit() you can access the data trough "history.state".
From the documentation: "State passed to any navigation. This value will be accessible through the extras object returned from router.getCurrentNavigation() while a navigation is executing. Once a navigation completes, this value will be written to history.state when the location.go or location.replaceState method is called before activating of this route."

Comment: Also make sure you don't try to recieve an extras object in `ngOnInit()` as `this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras`

Comment: What if are navigation to external url as route.navigate(['/externalUrlRedirect', {externalUrl: 'http://google.com'}], {state: {data{name:'mayank'}}}); than how to receive the same at other side . I had tried history.state but that only returns navigationId : 1 ?

Comment: @VégerLóránd @hastrb - why can't we use this in `ngOnInit()`

Comment: @KinleyChristian  Check out this answer, if you have further questions let me know! https://stackoverflow.com/a/54891361/4222504

Comment: What will happen if user reloads ? Its coming undefined :'(

Comment: Indeed, with this solution, you can not reload the page because you will lose the data. You can implement some guards to check if the data is actually there and if not (because of reloading) you just navigate back the user to that page where he can "grab" it. Here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JqCG3uhZQv0) that describes very well the differences between the different solutions.
Also at [15:27](https://youtu.be/JqCG3uhZQv0?t=927) the video mentions the reload problem.

Comment: If you are using this method to pass data between components than data will not be available once you refresh the page. Since you need to read the data from browser’s history object: like history.state.data and history will be cleared on page refresh. @VégerLóránd

Comment: @Amir Yes this is what I have said in my previous comment

Answer (score 74):

Latest version of angular (7.2 +) now has the option to pass additional information using **NavigationExtras**.

**Home component**

```js
import {
  Router,
  NavigationExtras
} from '@angular/router';
const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
  state: {
    transd: 'TRANS001',
    workQueue: false,
    services: 10,
    code: '003'
  }
};
this.router.navigate(['newComponent'], navigationExtras);
```

**newComponent**

```js
test: string;
constructor(private router: Router) {
  const navigation = this.router.getCurrentNavigation();
  const state = navigation.extras.state as {
    transId: string,
    workQueue: boolean,
    services: number,
    code: string
  };
  this.test = "Transaction Key:" + state.transId + "<br /> Configured:" + state.workQueue + "<br /> Services:" + state.services + "<br /> Code: " + state.code;
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Hope this would help!

Comment: I keep getting "navigation is null". I have tried several examples...

Comment: This is old, but for future visitors – you _have_ to call it inside the constructor. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54891361/2950032

Comment: Can you still access the state data after a page refresh?

Comment: ok I just tested this myself, and it works perfectly only directly after routing to the new component from the old one. Once you reload the page, the state is undefined : (

Comment: This works perfectly till the user reload the page. Then state will be undefined. :(

Answer (score 7):

I needed access to the data in `CustomRouteReuseStrategy` and I couldn't inject the `Router` there due to a circular dependency but you can use the `Location` object to read the state as well.

```
Send:

    this.router.navigate(['action-selection'], { state: { example: 'bar' } });

Receive:
    import { Location } from '@angular/common';

    constructor(private location: Location) {
      console.log(this.location.getState().example); // should log out 'bar'
    }
```

Comment: This way works well. If you want to use it entirely in the template, provide your `state` as bound input to the same element you're providing `routerLink` to. Eg:

   
`<button [routerLink]="['action-selection']" [state]="{ example: 'bar' }"> Navigate with State </button>`

Answer (score 5):

Since Angular 15, `this.router.getCurrentNavigation()` might return null, because the component is instantiated after the navigation.

The alternative is to access the state from the `Location` (the one from `@angular/common`)

```
  import { Location } from '@angular/common';

  constructor(private location: Location) {
    location.getState() // do what you want 
  }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75150492/1659605

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75173301/1659605

Answer (score 2):

In navigateExtra we can pass only some specific name as argument otherwise it showing error like below:
For Ex- Here I want to pass customer key in router navigate and I pass like this-

```
this.Router.navigate(['componentname'],{cuskey: {customerkey:response.key}});
```

but it showing some error like below:

```
Argument of type '{ cuskey: { customerkey: any; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NavigationExtras'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'cuskey' does not exist in type 'NavigationExt## Heading ##ras'
```

.

Solution:
we have to write like this:

```
this.Router.navigate(['componentname'],{state: {customerkey:response.key}});
```

Answer (score 1):

@dev-nish Your code works with little tweaks in them.
make the

```
const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
  state: {
    transd: 'TRANS001',
    workQueue: false,
    services: 10,
    code: '003'
  }
};
```

into

```
let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
  state: {
    transd: '',
    workQueue: ,
    services: ,
    code: ''
  }
};
```

then if you want to specifically sent a type of data, for example, JSON as a result of a form fill you can send the data in the same way as explained before.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69420764/7186739

Answer (score 1):

When the `NavigationEnd` event is emitted, it retrieves the current navigation state using `this.router.getCurrentNavigation()`.  If there is a navigation state available in the extras property of the navigation object, it logs the state to the console.

```
constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute
  ) {

    this.router.events
      .pipe(
        filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
        takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
      )
      .subscribe((event) => {
        const navigation = this.router.getCurrentNavigation();
        if (navigation && navigation.extras.state) {
          console.log(navigation.extras.state);
        }
      });
}


  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.unsubscribe$.next();
    this.unsubscribe$.complete();
  }
```

## Explanation from ChatGPT:

- The `this.router.events` property represents an observable that emits
  events related to navigation in the router.
- The pipe method allows you to chain multiple operators to the observable.
- In this case, the filter operator is used to only allow `NavigationEnd` events to pass through. This ensures that the code inside the subscribe callback is only executed when a navigation ends.
- The takeUntil operator is used to complete the observable when the `this.unsubscribe$` subject emits a
  value. This is done to clean up the subscription when the component
  is destroyed.
- Finally, inside the subscribe callback, the current
  navigation state is retrieved using
  `this.router.getCurrentNavigation()`. If there is a navigation state
  available and it has a state property in the extras object, the state
  is logged to the console.

**NB:** In the `ngOnDestroy` method, the `this.unsubscribe$.next()` method is called to emit a value and complete the `this.unsubscribe$` subject, which will in turn complete the `takeUntil` operator and unsubscribe from the router events.

## Optimize Code:

```
this.router.events
  .pipe(
    filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
    take(1) // Only take the first event
  )
  .subscribe((event) => {
    const navigation = this.router.getCurrentNavigation();
    if (navigation && navigation.extras.state) {
      console.log(navigation.extras.state);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getStateById(stateId) {
        return this.http.get<any>(environment.user_service_url + "/getStateById",
 {params:{"stateId": stateId}});
    }
```

Answer (score -15):

Best I found on internet for this is [ngx-navigation-with-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-navigation-with-data).
It is very simple and good for navigation the data from one component to another component.
You have to just import the component class and use it in very simple way.
Suppose you have home and about component and want to send data then

HOME COMPONENT

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgxNavigationWithDataComponent } from 'ngx-navigation-with-data';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-home',
 templateUrl: './home.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(public navCtrl: NgxNavigationWithDataComponent) { }

 ngOnInit() {
 }

 navigateToABout() {
  this.navCtrl.navigate('about', {name:"virendta"});
 }

}
```

ABOUT COMPONENT

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgxNavigationWithDataComponent } from 'ngx-navigation-with-data';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-about',
 templateUrl: './about.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./about.component.css']
})
export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {

 constructor(public navCtrl: NgxNavigationWithDataComponent) {
  console.log(this.navCtrl.get('name')); // it will console Virendra
  console.log(this.navCtrl.data); // it will console whole data object here
 }

 ngOnInit() {
 }

}
```

For any query follow https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-navigation-with-data

Comment down for help.

Comment: Does it transfer data in the form of params or just in the background?

Comment: I couldn't understand @MariumMalik
Can you please ask in a descriptive way?

Comment: Yes it does @MariumMalik

Comment: You appear to be the author of this, rather than "I found on the internet"? You are also being asked not to spam it on the Angular 7 thread that implements similar functionality (https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/27198)