# Passing value from one component to other component using Input property when using router-outlet

Tags: angular

I have my parent component where the  is defined to display other component(childComponent) when the route changes, I want to pass a value from parentComp to childComp, usually we include the selector in place of router-outlet if we don't use routes and pass using @Input property.
How can I achieve the same when using routes

ParentComponent

```
@Component({
    selector : 'parent',
    template : `<h1>Home</h1>
            <router-outlet test1="test"></router-outlet>
    `,
})
export class parentComp{
    test = "testing";
}
```

ChildCompoent

```
@Component({
    selector : 'child',
    template : `<h2>Home</h2>
    `,
})
export class childComp implements onChanges, onInit{
    @Input() test1;
    ngOnChanges(){
        console.log(this.test1);
    }
ngOnInit(){
            console.log(this.test1);
}
}
```

I want to get the value of test1 from parent to child component and print in console using @Input property.

I'm getting the value of test1 as undefined when printing the value in console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot define an `@Input()` variable for a `router-outlet`.

Instead you have the following as alternative options

- Use Route params
- Use Query params
- Shared service to share the data
- State Management using redux tools

Comment: Is there any way doing this using Input property

Comment: No. if you are using `router-outlet` its not possible. Refer this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44864303/sending-data-with-route-navigate-in-angular-2/44865817#44865817) for alternative options.

Comment: @DeborahK the above answer is valid one or did I miss any