# how can we share data btw components across modules in angular4?

Tags: angular

I am trying to share data between components across two different modules . I am using a shared service  and  BehaviorSubject to acheive this.

works perfectly in components in same module , but no luck for components in a different module. Any advice ?

Comment: What you have tried so far. 

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: [This](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/) article has a good description of this via dependency injection of a service. This should be best as it's implementing the Singleton and Observer patterns and it is very easy to scale and maintain.

Comment: Refer this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44867021/passing-value-from-one-component-to-other-component-using-input-property-when-us/44867072#44867072)

Answer (score 0):

May be this one can solve your issue 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xrknuj

Comment: my case i have sharedmodule  which is known to module 1 and module 2, shared service is known to sharedmodule (added in providers). component1 in module1 and component 2 in module 2 is subscribing a BehaviorSubject in  shared service .  data change triggered by component 1  is not subscribing in component 2

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz for that problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried **exporting** your component from the shared module?  If so, you can then use component outputs (if they are adjacent) or a service (if they are not adjacent) like you mentioned to share data between two components.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { MyComponent } from '../components/my-component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    MyComponent,
  ],
  exports: [
    MyComponent,
  ],
})

export class SharedModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

That should work with services across different modules as well. Do your modules know about each other?

A possible architecture could be like this:
`Module1` and `Module2` want share some data. Then you have a `Shared` module, which imports BOTH, `Module1` and `Module2`. In this case the communication should work.

Please see more information here:
https://medium.com/dailyjs/3-ways-to-communicate-between-angular-components-a1e3f3304ecb
(Your solution is no. 3)

Comment: my case i have sharedmodule  which is known to module 1 and module 2, shared service is known to sharedmodule (added in providers). component1 in module1 and component 2 in module 2 is subscribing a BehaviorSubject in  shared service .  data change triggered by component 1  is not subscribing in component 2