# passing data between components or route, angular4

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a list of cards, each card has some data like `{"phone":"333-123-4566", "cust_name":"john smith"}`

I have a list component and a card component to display the phone and name.

How does angular2 or angular4 pass the item data into card component?
I need to know which card is clicked and display the right phone/name.

In Angular 1, it was very simple with ngModel, but I am not finding a simple solution in angular2/4.

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index;">
    <a routerLink="/card" > {{item.cust_name}} </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/10/resolving-route-data-in-angular-2.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two most common choices are:

1) Pass the information as part of the route. You can do this three ways: required, optional, or query parameters.

I have details on this here: [Sending data with route.navigate in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44864303/sending-data-with-route-navigate-in-angular-2/44865817#44865817)

2) Define a service that holds the data and access that service from both components.

I have an example of this here: https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/build-a-simple-angular-service-to-share-data/

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index;">
        <a routerLink="['/card', {"phone":"333-123-4566", "cust_name":"john smith"}]"> {{item.cust_name}} </a>
      </li>
    </ul>     

<ul>
      <li *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index;">
        <a (click)=navigate(item)> {{item.cust_name}} </a>
      </li>
    </ul> 


navigate(item) : void {  
  this.router.navigate(['/card', {"phone":"333-123-4566", "cust_name":"john smith"}])
}
```