# How can we save state of component in angular 2?

Tags: angular

I know lots have already asked this question but none of them gave clear answer. I just want to store the state of component when it navigates to another and then come back to previous one. I know we can save the data in service and then fetch the dats back to component. But, I think this is easy but not the better solution when the component is too complex. I read some router reuse things but non of them work in angular 2.

Comment: Can you provide the questions that don't provide a clear answers? This is a possible duplicate and have answered many times before

Comment: You can't save data in a component since when its destructed the data will go away

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several options:

1) Use a service. This is actually one of the best ways if the data is complex. I have a simple example here: https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/build-a-simple-angular-service-to-share-data/

2) Routing parameters. You can specify required, optional, or query parameters. See this for more information: [Sending data with route.navigate in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44864303/sending-data-with-route-navigate-in-angular-2/44865817#44865817)

If you are looking for information on the router reuse strategies, you can find some information here: https://medium.com/@juliapassynkova/angular-2-component-reuse-strategy-9f3ddfab23f5

Comment: Asked this question around July 2017 and now in 2018, what I understand is simply save the data in service file and again use that data when you comes back on that page. Hence other answer still didn't come from @angular team.

Comment: I don't believe that the Angular team monitors these forums. Stackoverflow is community supported. We are all just volunteers here.

Comment: I updated my answer above to provide information on router reuse as well if that is what you are really looking for?

Comment: this is why I don't want to use Ionic4 (angular based routing) and keep Ionic3 (it keeps the component state automaticly!)