# Angular 4 - Route query params cause path match failure

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, url-encoding, query-string

After searching multiple threads/questions on the various types of routing within Angular 4, I cannot resolve an issue linked to passing queryParams to an Angular 4 route.

When passing either into the url

```
http://localhost/search;x=y
```

through the template [queryParams]={x: 'y'}

```
<a [routerLink]="/search" [queryParams]="{x: 'y'}">Navigate</a>
```

or in the component class

```
this._router.navigate(['/search'], { queryParams: {x: 'y'} });
```

the result is the router throwing a match error:

```
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'search%3Fparam1%3Dtest1%26param2%3Dtest2'
```

When setting enableTracing to true, I can see the navigation encodes the suspect characters, which most likely is the reason it's failing to match.

I have a requirement to handle urls that contain queryParams and parse them for api calls, so the query param route must be used over required or optional params.

Has anyone had a similar issue and if so, is the encoding the root (ahem.) cause of the issue?

Comment: Could you show us the path of your route in the definition ? It should be `{ path: 'search/:x', component: MyComponent}`. If not, here is your error !

Comment: Not quite. QueryParams should **not** be defined in the route definition. If they are ... then *that* is the problem. :-)

Answer (score 24):

Query parameters result in a url that looks like this:

```
http://localhost/search?x=y
```

With a question mark, not a semicolon.

Here is a summary for how to work with query parameters.

[image]

Note that they are **not** configured as part of the route definition.

Your routerLink and navigate method looks correct.

**Update :**
make sure to use this import.

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
```

Comment: Your router.navigate call has the closing square bracket in the wrong place, needs to be ['/products'], { etc... }.

Comment: You are right. I had fixed it in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44864303/sending-data-with-route-navigate-in-angular-2/44865817#44865817 But missed this one.

Answer (score 12):

After some deliberation I was able to fix the issue.

I was using ActivatedRouteSnapshot to store the url (including query params) as a whole, then passing that through to the router.

I should have stored the query params in a separate object to the route and passed them in using

```
this._router.navigate(['/search'], { queryParams: paramsObj });
```

Of course the route matching failed as it couldn't match a route with all the query params added onto the end of the string.

Answer (score 3):

For example, you want to add a link that will redirect to the search page with variable: searchString = 'search'

```html
<a [routerLink]="['/search', searchString]">Navigate</a>
```

In your component, you can create a navigation by using `this._router.navigate(['/search', this.searchString]);`, where searchString is declared as a const in both cases.

Answer (score 2):

Following code saved me:

```
         this.router.navigate(['route-name'], { queryParams: {key:'value'} });
```

On the receiving end fetch the value by: ( I assume ActivatedRoute is injected place),

```
         this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {console.log(queryParams['key'])}
```

Or at template level you can write like this.

```
 **<a [routerLink]="['/login']" [queryParams]="{ key: 'employer'}" >sign in</a></p>**
```

Note: route is an instance of ActivatedRoute.