# Enforce queryParameters in Angular 4 router

Tags: angular, routes, query-string

I am trying to use this syntax to navigate with `queryParams` following the accepted answer in here: [Sending data with route.navigate in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44864303/sending-data-with-route-navigate-in-angular-2)

```
this.router.navigate(['add', { queryParams: { type: $event.value } }], { relativeTo: this.route });
```

However instead of:
`.../add?type=someEventValue`

this results in the optional parameters (aka matrix notation)

`.../add;queryParams=%5Bobject%20Object%5D`

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to enforce the old style of search parameters in Angular 4.3.x router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add optional parameters to the root route, you'll get `?param=value`, if you add it to a child route, you'll get `;param=value`.

Angular needs this to distinguish which route params belong to.

Comment: So you mean that queryParams are available only from the level of root component (eg. app.component.ts)?

Comment: Exactly. Query params added to other route segements result in matrix parameter form.

Answer (score 0):

The queryParams object should be a part of the second argument that you pass when you call the `navigate` function.

What you should do is the following:

```
this.router.navigate(['add'], { queryParams: { type: $event.value }, relativeTo: this.route });
```