# Angular: How to extract parameters from child routes?

Tags: angular

Let's say I've this table

```
+--------------------+-------+----------+---------+
| Label | Date       | Items | Location |         |
+-------+------------+-------+----------+---------+
| REF 1 | 12/12/2017 | 3     | Floor 1  | Details |
+-------+------------+-------+----------+---------+
| TXD 7 | 12/31/2017 | 1     | Floor 3  | Details |
+-------+------------+-------+----------+---------+
```

`Details` is a button. When user clicks the the **Details** button, div with tabs should display on the bottom.

```
+------------------------+
| TAB 1  | TAB 2 | TAB 3 |
+--------+-------+-------+------------------------+
|                                                 |
| Content of the TAB 1                            |
|                                                 |
|                                                 |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

Here's the routing

```
RouterModule.forChild([
  { 
    path: 'gift', component: GiftComponent, 
  },
  {
    path: 'gift/:id', component: GiftComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'giftItemList', pathMatch: 'full'},
      { path: 'giftItemList', component: GiftItemListComponent },
      { path: 'giftItemDetails', component: GiftItemDetailsComponent }
    ]
  }      
])
```

When user the Gift link from the menu `<li><a [routerLink]="'/gift'">Gift</a></li>`, the gift component is displayed. Only the upper portion is displayed.

If the user clicks the Details button,

```
 <td>
     <button (click)="displayGiftItems(gift.id)" class="btn btn-link">
        Details
     </button>
</td>
```

Then **displayGiftItems** function from the component is called. It makes the the surrounding DIV visible where the child component will be displayed. Then it navigate to the child component.

```
 displayGiftItems(id: number, e) {
if (id) {
  this.giftItemsPanelIsVisible = true;  
  this.router.navigate(['giftItemList'], { relativeTo: this.route});
}
```

}

When I click the Details button, the url doesn't have this form: `gift/1/giftItemList`.

How to get such url and how to extract parameters from this url?

Thanks for helping

Comment: What form does your url have? I don't see anywhere that you are actually adding the id to the route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
displayGiftItems(id: number, e) {
if (id) {
  this.giftItemsPanelIsVisible = true;  
  this.router.navigate(['gift', id, 'giftItemList']);
}
```

You then read it something like this:

```
const id = route.paramMap.get('id');
```

For more information, see this post: 
[Sending data with route.navigate in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44864303/sending-data-with-route-navigate-in-angular-2/44865817#44865817)

Comment: Hi Deborah, I'm learning Angular watching your course now on pluralsight. At least, this time the url is in the right form: `http://localhost:4200/gift/1/giftItemList`. But nothing is happening on the bottom. When I comment out this line `this.router.navigate(['gift', id, 'giftItemList']);`, the panel appears. Otherwise, nothing happens (

Comment: :-) Would it be possible to build a plunker that demonstrates your issue? Otherwise you can view the example applications posted to my github for suggestions on routing. My "Angular Routing" course shows how to implement routed tabs.

Comment: The problem was that I had a little understanding of the way Angular routing works. I've watched your course on routing and solve this and other issues I was experiencing.