# Wrong URL is read when I want to pass a parameter in my URL

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-router

I want to pass a parameter in my URL when a search button is clicked.
I wanted it to look like this. 
/result?search=sap

However, I am getting this error in console.
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'result;search=sap'
I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Here is my code.

SearchComponent.ts

```
search(){
    //this function is accessed when a user clicks on a search button in the HTML
    this.router.navigate(['/result', { search: this.query }]);
    //this.query = sap
}
```

AppModule.ts

```
 const routes: Routes = [
    //other routes here
  { path: 'result/:search', component: SearchComponent}
 ];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    //other components
    SearchComponent
  ] ,
  imports: [
    //other modules
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {}),

  ],
```

Comment: You are mixing required parameter syntax (with the `:search` on the route) with optional parameter syntax in the `this.router.navigate`. See this post that outlines which syntax goes with which route parameter type: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44864303/sending-data-with-route-navigate-in-angular-2/44865817#44865817

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want query parameters, your route configuration needs to look like this:

```
 const routes: Routes = [
    //other routes here
  { path: 'result', component: SearchComponent}
 ];
```

Query parameters are optional, so are *not* included in the route configuration.

And the syntax for query parameters in the `navigate` is as follows:

```
this.router.navigate(['/result'], 
                     {queryParams: { search: this.query }});
```

The resulting URL then should look something like this:

```
http://localhost:4200/result?search=sap
```

See this post for more information: [Sending data with route.navigate in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44864303/sending-data-with-route-navigate-in-angular-2/44865817#44865817)

Comment: This solution worked perfectly. Thank you so much. I guess i was following the wrong reference material.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is mixing 2 different url parameters technique.

**1.  { path: 'result/:search', component: SearchComponent}**
This is parameterized url technique. Itt means that this url must always have something after result part.

For ex:

result/qwe ( here qwe will get mapped to search)

result/asdasd ( here asdasd will get mapped to search )

result ( this is error since there is no part after result)

**2. result?search=qwe**

Here, the parameter **search** is optional.If you want your url to work like **/result?search=qwer**, then
a. Keep your routes to **{ path: 'result', component: SearchComponent}**.
b. Use param of Route or ActivatedRoute. Like **this.route.param.subscribe(param => console.log(param))**