# Angular Routing with query params for product filter

Tags: angular, routes

Hello I am trying to use query params so that it can filter my json data [for that I am using a service].

```
<a [routerLink]="['/shop']" [queryParams]="{ type: 'jeans'}">Jeans</a>
```

I am trying to get the data from the service but failing to do so. The data is in JSON format used by the service. So If a user clicks the link it should filter the relevant product category and data under it.

```
ngOnInit() {
this.productList = this.productservice.getProducts();
this.activatedRoute.queryParams
  .subscribe(queryParams => {
    if (queryParams.type === 'product1') {
       this.productList['productCategory'] == 'Jeans'; /* dont know if its correct*/
    } else if(queryParams.type === 'product2') {
       this.productList['productCategory'] == 'Shirts';
    }
  })
}
```

The data which is getting from the service -

```
import { Products } from './products';

export const PRODUCTS: Products[] = [
{
id: 1,
productCat:'product2',
product: [
    {
        prodId: 1a,
        productCategory:'product1',
        productName: 'Prod Desc',
    },
 ],
 },
 {
    id: 2,
    productCategory:'product2',
    product: [
    {
        prodId: 1b;
        productName: 'Trendy Shirts',
    },
  ],
 }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this is what you are looking for:

```
let filteredProductList = this.productList.filter(product=> product.productCategory == 'Jeans'); //For getting multiple matching results

let filteredProduct = this.productList.find(product=> product.productCategory == 'Jeans'); //For getting single matching result
```

Comment: Hi @Prachi the JSON data is not getting filter. May be some modification to the code?

Comment: Is console showing any error or the object is returned null?

Comment: Hi @Prachi in console `console.log(filteredProduct);` the data is getting what we want. May be there is a problem with `query params` can we do it with another method?

Comment: How you have defined your route?

Comment: Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44864303/send-data-through-routing-paths-in-angular

Comment: Hi @Prachi, its like this `{path: 'shop', component: ShopComponent},` And I have added and where should I add this - `this.router.navigate(['/shop'], {queryParams: {type: 'jeans'}});
          this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('type');` I have added in query params if else block

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170715/discussion-between-prachi-and-akshay).