# Passing Parameters to Angular CLI

Tags: angular, typescript, parameters, angular-ui-router

I have an angular application that lunches from another asp.net applicatin.
 my questions :

**example( asp.net application will send the following url to my angular application**

http://example.com?id=1&user="john M"

1. how my Angular CLI application can get/read the above parameters.
2. how my Angular CLI application can verify the referral URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be clear on the terminology, the Angular CLI is a command line tool that you use to create an Angular application, generate code for that application, execute tests, and build. I assume you mean an Angular application and not that you are sending this command to the Angular CLI.

I assume you will be able to perform the routing and read the parameters just like if the user typed in the URL. You can read about Angular routing here: https://angular.io/guide/router

Here is a snippet showing how to read in query parameters using the router:

```
    this.id= this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('id');
    this.user= this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('user');
```

Comment: Thanks DeborahK, Yes, CLI is just a command line..the confusion I have is when navigating from within an application I do use "  { path: ':id/:name', component: SearchComponent }" then in my component I do   this._rout.params.subscribe(params => {
            
            this.dashboardStatusID = params['id'];
            this.dashboardSatusName = params['name'];
           
        });

Comment: That is the code for required parameters, which have a different syntax from query parameters. See this link for a description of the difference between required and query parameters: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44864303/send-data-through-routing-paths-in-angular/44865817#44865817