# How to pass query parameters with question mark from other web site to angular 6 spa

Tags: angular, routes, angular6

I got 2 web applications **A** and **B**. The web Application B is the Angular 6 base.

In web application **A**, it got a link which is referring to B with query string like http://B/receipt?referencenumber=11111&title=test&description=sdfsd.

In web application **B**, I have define route like below.

```
{ path: 'receipt/:referencenumber/:title/:description', component: ReceiptComponent},
{ path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
{ path: 'error', component: ErrorComponent },
{ path: '**', component: ErrorComponent, data: { error: 404 } }
```

**Issue**:

if web application **A**, use the link http://B/receipt?referencenumber=11111&title=test&description=sdfsd, it would be redirected to 404 error page in web applicaiton B.

Anyone got Idea here? I have tried to modify the route in web application to 
 { path: 'receipt/:referencenumber', component: ReceiptComponent}, and change the linke in web application A to http://B/receipt?referencenumber=11111, it still redirect to 404.

Moreover, I have tried route below with the optional query parameters, it is still not working. (Ref: [Send data through routing paths in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44864303/send-data-through-routing-paths-in-angular))
 { path: 'receipt', component: ReceiptComponent}

**Update**

After I remove the error page, I found that the url is automatically encoded, it become http://B/receipt%3Freferencenumber%3D123123  not sure why also?

Comment: In your route, `referenceNumber`, `title`, and `description` are set up as path parameters, not query string parameters. Remove those bits from your path so it's just `receipt`

Comment: I have tried that, it is still redirect to the error 404 page

Comment: Seems to work in a StackBlitz? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nafraa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts If possiblee, please feel free to fork that Stackblitz and reproduce the issue

Comment: After I remove the error page, I found that the url is automatically encoded, it become http://B/receipt%3Freferencenumber%3D123123 not sure why also?

Comment: How are you navigating to that page? If you just paste the correct URL into the address bar, does it work?

Comment: navigating is only working in the web applicaiton B, if the web application A referring the url, it would not be working.

Comment: But how are you going from A to B? What code are you using to do that? It should work fine. If I create a hyperlink like https://angular-nafraa.stackblitz.io/receipt?referencenumber=999 it seems to work fine

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have mixed the `url` and `queryParams`

> `{ path: 'receipt/:referencenumber/:title/:description', component: ReceiptComponent},`

would match the url like `https://yoursite.com/receipt/dynamicNumber/dynamicTitle/dynamicDescription`

to get this url `http://B/receipt?referencenumber=11111&title=test&description=sdfsd` on `ReceiptComponent`, just remove `dynamic` parts after `receipt`:

`{ path: 'receipt', component: ReceiptComponent}`

to get [`queryParams`](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/query_params.html) in component use `this.route.queryParams` via `subscriber` or `this.route.snapshot.queryParams` via `direct` property name

Answer (score 2):

Finally, find the issue. one of my Auth intercepter using navigate() cause the issue, it should use the navigateByUrl() instead.