# How to send data from a component to another that is not a child/parent to display a message (flash message)

Tags: angular, http, angular7

I want to show a message on the login component if the user came from a successful registration process. I know that the question "how to pass data from one component to another" is very common But a few times someone know a technique that is very easy and good to apply. The components are not in a parent/child structure, I don't want to use query strings (worst solution in my opinion), preferably I don't want to go throught all the trouble to create a shared service.

Is there some way to do something like:

```
   this.router.navigateByUrl('login', {data_available_only_in_this_request: true})
```

I am redirecting the user if the registration was successful to the login component and passing some data. Here I am only showing how easy I want things to be.

I am searching an easy way to do this, I think creating a facility only to show a message too much.

Comment: The "easier" way will probably cost you more time and effort.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44864303/send-data-through-routing-paths-in-angular (if using Angular 7 check the NavigationExtras.state )

Answer (score 0):

there is actually a way to achieve this, by storing data in the object and then set to local storage.
example:

```
 let obj={
name:'',
item:''}


localStorage.setItem('object',JSON.stringify(obj));
```

then where ever you want to get use this,

```
let x =  localStorage.getItem('object')
var y= JSON.parse(x);
```

IF you are really not interested to use HelperComponent this would help you better.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a data service for pass data from one component to another component.

Please check [this link's](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/) data.service.ts section for more detail.

if this method is not working for you then store data in localstorage with custom controller id and fetch from localstorage where you need it.

Comment: I know ,that's the only "good" solution I can think of. But I only wish it could be an easier way.

Comment: Then store your data in localstorage with component id and fetch in other component