# what is the $location.search() in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

how to use the $location.search in angular 4

```
var queryParams = $location.search(); -- in angular

 setDefaultLanguage() {
    var queryParams = $location.search();
    if (queryParams.locale) {
        var locale = queryParams.locale;
        var selectedLanguageArray = languageOptions.filter(function (lang:any) {
            return String(lang.id).toLocaleLowerCase() === String(locale).toLocaleLowerCase();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$location.search() equivalent in Angular 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54772646/location-search-equivalent-in-angular-7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the activated route:

```
export class AppComponent {
     constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) {
         route.queryParams.pipe(
             filter(q => !!q.locale),
             map(q => q.locale as string),
             distinctUntilChanged()
         ).subscribe(locale => console.log(locale));
    }
 }
```

Or if you only want to have it onces you can get it from the snapshot:

```
    if (route.snapshot.queryParams.locale) {
        const locale = route.snapshot.queryParams.locale;
        const selectedLanguageArray = languageOptions.filter(function (lang: any) {
            return String(lang.id).toLocaleLowerCase() === String(locale).toLocaleLowerCase();
        });
    }
```