# Router getCurrentNavigation always returns null

Tags: angular

In the latest version of Angular 7.2.6, I'm trying to pass data in router itself

```
this.router.navigate(['other'], {state: {someData: 'qwert'}}
```

In the `OtherComponent` file, `this.router.getCurrentNavigation()` always return null

[Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uapqsj)

[Angular Docs - getCurrentNavigation](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#getcurrentnavigation)

[Angular Docs - state](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#state)

Comment: Where are you calling the function? I think `ngOnInit()` would be too late, as the navigation has already completed https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/7.2.6/packages/router/src/router.ts#L711

Comment: In `OtherComponent`, and modified it to be in `constructor` and it worked!

Answer (score 225, accepted):

You're calling the method `getCurrentNavigation` too late. The navigation has finished.

You need call the `getCurrentNavigation` method inside of the constructor:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.name = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.someData;
}
```

Or if you want to access the navigation in `ngOnInit` you can do following:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.name = history.state.someData;
}
```

Comment: @Carlos.V no it does not! :\

Comment: this did not work for me when navigation is from InitializeApp in app.component

Comment: In my case, I was using this in `ngOnInit` but after awaiting for another method to complete, so it evaluated to null. Works as expected when fired independently within the `ngOnInit` method!

Comment: any disadvantages by using history over router.GetCurrentNavigation() ?

Comment: history is a browser-specific API. So if you're building only for browser - no downsides

Comment: For issues with Angular 15+ see @Matthieu Riegler answer

Answer (score 22):

Since Angular 16, there is [`lastSuccessfulNavigation`](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#lastSuccessfulNavigation) to replace the breaking change that was introduced in v15 where `getCurrentNavigation` might return `null`.

---

##### Pre v16 answer:

Since Angular 15, `this.router.getCurrentNavigation()` might return null, because the component is instantiated after the navigation.

The alternative is to access the state from the `Location` (the one from `@angular/common`)

```
  import { Location } from '@angular/common';

  constructor(private location: Location) {
    location.getState() // do what you want 
  }
```

Comment: This worked for me in Angular 14!

Comment: Can you please show how to access the `someData` property,when using the `location.getState()` object?

Comment: It should be `location.getState().someData`.

Comment: Got error: "Object is of type 'unknown'" in that case and had to define `interface State {  someData: any;  }` to receive the value of `someData` via `const state = location.getState() as State; console.log(state.someData);`. Is there a more general way to resolve the parameters from `getState()`, because I don't want to define interfaces all over the app, where I use certain parameters for navigation?

Comment: You can always assert as `any`.

Comment: Excellent answer.. our code was broken after ng16 upgrade... this is how I fixed it

this.navigationData = this.router.lastSuccessfulNavigation?.extras.state as NavigationData;

Put the above inside the ctor

Answer (score 12):

change the code like this because after `constructor()` only the `ngOnInit()` gets called so the value is getting null

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
   this.name = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.example;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since Angular 16, there is `lastSuccessfulNavigation` to replace the breaking change that was introduced in v15 where `getCurrentNavigation` might return `null`.

Comment: I suggest updating your previous answer about location.getState() instead of adding another one, since it's now likely the more appropriate approach.

Comment: Property 'lastSuccessfulNavigation' is private and only accessible within class 'Router'

Comment: @Ems https://angular.io/api/router/Router#lastSuccessfulNavigation it is very much public.

Comment: I just copied/pasted the error message I got when I implemented this solution... What worked for me was using getState() instead of lastSuccessfulNavigation. I am using Angular 14.

Answer (score 2):

If your path is registered with a parameter:

```
{path: 'somePath/:id', component: SomeComponent}
```

It's important to navigate to it correctly:

```
this.router.navigate(['/some', id], {state: {data: id}});
```

Incorrect would be:

```
this.router.navigate(['/some'+'/'+id], {state: {data: id}});
```

Angular does not warn you about incorrect usage and **this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state** is not set.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me because there was a promise (asynchronous process) in the Event of the NavigationEnd, before consuming the **getCurrentNavigation().extras().state** of the current state.

I moved the promise after and voila! It managed to get the data without first being cleaned.

Answer (score 0):

For spec (tests), the `getCurrentNavigation()` on `constructor` don´t work, you have to use the `history` at `ngOnInit()` and mock values at `history`, for example:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    window.history.pushState({name: 'MyName', id: 1}, '', '');
}
```

Now your component can use this values on `ngOnInit`() and use on spec.:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(history.state.name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To persist state use navigateByUrl

```
this.route.navigateByUrl('/your-route', { state: { id:some_id, name:'your_data' } );
<a [routerLink]="['dynamic']" [state]="{ { id:some_id, name:'your_data' }}">Dynamic Data</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution as follows for angular v16:

First, set the router

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'hero/:id',
    component: ChildComponent,
  },
];
```

When we need to obtain the ID in our component, such as when fetching a hero using its ID, we would do the following in the component:

```
export class ChildComponent {
  constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) {
    route.params.subscribe((params) => // do whatever you want with params.id);
  } 
}
```

Now we can use @Input for that. It's as simple as that.

```
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() id: string;
}
```

Answer (score -9):

work for me Ionic 4

- this.router.url => /app/menu/etc       // current position