# Angular cannot get the @inputData for routing - getCurrentNavigation() method returns null value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
<app-example [id]="requestId"></app-example>
```

We have add the selector in another component with passing the id.

```
export class exampleComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() id:number;

Id:string;

}
```

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private _AppService: AppService, private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
        this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state != undefined ? this.Id = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.key : '';
        this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
            this.current_path = data.urlname;
        })
}
```

we've using the getCurrentNavigation() method,
but its return null value

Comment: checkout this solution. may be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54891110/router-getcurrentnavigation-always-returns-null

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
constructor(private router: Router) {

router.events.subscribe((event) => {
  if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
    this.current_path = event.url;
 }
})
```