# ionic 4 angular getCurrentNavigation() is null in ionViewDidEnter

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, angular8

I have tabs navigation in my ionic 4 app. The scenario is from `tab5`page user is redirected to `add-address` page. After adding the address user gets redirected to the `tab5` page again.

The way ionic works constructor of `tab5` page doesn't get called when the user is redirected from `add-address` page to `tab5` page again. That is the reason I am trying to access router `getCurrentNavigation()` in `ionViewDidEnter`. But it is null. I am not getting why.

Here is the code

Thank you in advance

tabbar-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabbarPage,
    children : [
      {
        path: 'tab1',
        loadChildren: () => import('../tab1/tab1.module').then( m => m.Tab1PageModule)
      },

      {
        path: 'tab5',
        loadChildren: () => import('../carts/carts.module').then( m => m.CartsPageModule),
      },

      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }

];
```

tab5-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [

  { path: '', redirectTo: 'tab5', pathMatch: 'full' },

  {
    path: '', children:[

      { path :'', component : CartsPage },

      { path: 'add-address', loadChildren: () => import('../add-address/add-address.module').then(m => m.AddAddressPageModule) },
      { path : 'payment-options', loadChildren : () => import('../payment-options/payment-options.module').then(m => m.PaymentOptionsPageModule)}
  
    ]
  }
];
```

add-address.page.ts

```
let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
            state: {
              added_address : check,
              address_id : this.edit_Address.address_id
            }
          };
  
          this.router.navigate(['tabs/tab5'], navigationExtras)
```

tab5.page.ts

```
ionViewDidEnter(){
    console.log(this.router.getCurrentNavigation()) // it is null
  }
```

Comment: Is `router` in your component constructor? Does your `tab5.module` have `RouterModule.forChild(routes)` declared in imports?

Comment: Yeah. Router is injected in contstruor of tab5 page and RouterModule.forchild(routes) is declared in tab.module

Comment: try calling it in the constructor per: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54891110/router-getcurrentnavigation-always-returns-null