# Passing object from on component to other with different routes

Tags: javascript, angular

I am in new in Angular 6. I am creating an app using Angular 6. During development I ran into a problem which is to share the data between components.
Here is the code:

I have two components
1) Signup
2) Verification

Signup is opened from route `/signup` and verification is opened from `/verification`.
Now what i want to pass the object from signup to verification component

Here is my sample code.

```
signup(){
  let someobject = {"name":"name"} // this data I want to pass in verification
  this.router.navigateByUrl('/verfication);
}

// second is the verfication component
export class verfication Component implements OnInit {

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() { }
}
```

Comment: This post covers it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44864303/send-data-through-routing-paths-in-angular

Answer (score 0):

You can use a service to store the data. 
And both the components can get the data from the service

Say let the service contain two methods and variable 
     Const  data;
     SetData(newdata) // set the variable here
     getData() // return the variable here
When u get the date a, call setData method of service. 
And in another component u can get the data using getData method

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to have a global service injected into main module and share data using local variable of that service