# How to upgrade Angular to the latest?

Tags: angular

I want to use the routing [state](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54365098/3408531), described also [here](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#state), for the version 7.2.x of Angular, I have 7.1.1 currently, I tried uninstalling and reinstalling CLI globaly and locally, but no change, how can I upgrade Angular?

```
 dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^7.2.14",
"@angular/cdk": "^7.3.6",
"@angular/cli": "^7.3.9",
"@angular/common": "^7.1.1",
"@angular/core": "^7.1.1",
"@angular/forms": "^7.1.1",
"@angular/http": "^7.1.1",
"@angular/material": "^7.3.6",
"@angular/router": "^7.1.1",    //This one does not help.
 ....
 },
```

Comment: This blog may be usefull http://laxmanchavda.blogspot.com/2021/05/upgrade-angular-version-to-latest.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following command

```
ng update @angular/cli@7.2.x
```

and just the following to see what all can be updated

```
ng update
```

Comment: ng update, only suggested cdk,core, material and rxjs, while others still 7.1.1! can I update routing specifically?

Comment: yes you can update any specific package you want...use the 1st command I mentioned