# Passing query parameter by using navigateByUrl()

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7, angular-routing

I am trying to Navigate to a new page on click of an icon and below is the code

```
  this.prj = e.data.project_number;
  this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard/ProjectShipment/634');
```

Instead of this hardcoded query parameter `000634` I have to pass a `this.prj` in to it. My path is like below

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
  path: 'dB',
  data: { title: 'Dashboard' },
  children: [
      {
          path: 'ProjectShipment/:reportProject',
          component: ProjectShipmentComponent,
          data: { title: 'Project Shipment' },
      }
```

Comment: I think you are talking about PATH parameter, not QUERY parameter. If you are trying to pass path param, MuruGan's answer is the right one and url will look like '/dashboard/ProjectShipment/634'. But if we are talking about query parameters, then Miguel Pinto's answer is the right one and the url will look smth like '/dashboard/ProjectShipment?prj=634'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply use string interpolation

```
this.router.navigateByUrl(`/dashboard/ProjectShipment/${this.prj}`);
```

Comment: what if prj is an object?

Comment: what can we specify the route.module.ts

Answer (score 15):

You can use 'router.navigate' instead of 'router.navigateByUrl':

```
this.router.navigate([URL], {queryParams: {id: this.prj}});
```

Comment: Argument of type '{ queryParams: { id: any; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NavigationBehaviorOptions'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'queryParams' does not exist in type 'NavigationBehaviorOptions'.ts(2345)

Answer (score 4):

```
// Set our navigation extras object
// that passes on our global query params and fragment
let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
  queryParams: {...},
  state: {...}
};

// Redirect the user
this.router.navigateByUrl(redirect, navigationExtras);
```

[NavigationExtras docs](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras)

EDIT: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44865817/5011818 this is also worth to look at

Comment: It is worth to comment that your answer seems right if you read the documentation, but it is wrong: `navigateByUrl` ignores those `NavigationExtras`. Related issues requesting an update of Angular docs: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/22668. and https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18798

Answer (score -3):

`this.router.navigate(['/route1'], { variable1: "Value" });`
`this.router.navigateByUrl('/route1', { variable1: "Value" });`

Please none: if your url is `urlencoded` use `navigateByUrl`, if your url is not `urlencoded` use `navigate`