# Angular 7 router.navigate with message after redirecting

Tags: angular

I'm using this code to redirect `this.router.navigate(['/abc']);`. How to show some message on the new page using `<ngb-alert>`, Is it possible to pass some variable while redirecting but not as url query parameters?

Comment: Why not use some service?
when you redirect check on ngOnInit for message on side service.
easy.

Comment: which Angular version are you using ? Angular 7.2 has state in NavigationExtras. You can use 'state' in NavigationExtras and read that state.

Comment: @Buzzinga I'm using 7.3. I will test it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that with `State` as below:

When you want to navigate set `state`:

```
const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {state: {data: 'This is an example'}};
this.router.navigate(['/abc'], navigationExtras);
```

In destination component you can get data like the following:

```
data:string;
constructor(private router: Router) { 
   const navigation = this.router.getCurrentNavigation();
   const state = navigation.extras.state as {data: string};
   this.data = state.data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a service to pass data from one component to another without using route parameters at all.

Their is already a datailed topic about this.
[Send data through routing paths in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44864303/send-data-through-routing-paths-in-angular)