# Using window.history.state Causing Error On Page Reload In Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, web, browser

I'm using the following code to pass data to a route:

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/myurl/goes/here', { state: { data: someData });
```

Now in the component i navigate to, i use the following code to get the data i passed from the first component.

```
this.incomingData = window.history.state.data;
```

Now the issue arrises when I reload the second component (Component B), i get an error telling my the data I passed to it is now undefined. (this.incomingData becomes undefined).

Is what am doing the correct way to pass and receive data between components or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: here is the link it will help you how to pass data and get it in another component 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44864303/send-data-through-routing-paths-in-angular

Answer (score -1):

Use angular `ActivatedRoute` service in component, that you navigate to

```
 constructor(activeRoute: ActivatedRoute) {

    // this.activeRoute.snapshot.data
    console.log('Route Data', this.activeRoute.snapshot.data)
  }
```