# After Submit form navigate to different component and show success message in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a component that send data to a service to save data in DB. After that i want to redirect or navigate to a different component and show success message there. I have implement it but i always get the wrong value. I am also not sure if i have implement it correct.Any help is welcome. Here is my code.

```
  Component class on submit etc {
    .....
   this.Service.updatePassword(this.neuesPassword);  //this will call the updatepassword  on service
   //after it will navigate to and pass queryParams
   this.router.navigateByUrl('/url',{ queryParams: { response: this.response } });
   }
    //this is the service method that is called 
   public updatePassword(newPass: string) {
    let payload = new HttpParams();
    payload = payload.set('Pass', newPass);
    this.httpClient.post(this.URL_UPDATE_PASSWORD, { newPassword }).subscribe((response: boolean) => {
        this.isSaved = response;           
    });
```

at the component i want to show the message i have on  ngOnInit() {
  } method this

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
  this._isChanged = params['response'];

});
```

and i want the _isChanged variable to get the value of the response. Something i am doing wrong . 
I have also look here [send-data-through-routing-paths-in-angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44864303/send-data-through-routing-paths-in-angular)

but i am doing something wrong. Any help wth that . thanks

Comment: where the variable ```this.response``` comes from?

Comment: in the service method. your argument is newPass but the .post is using newPassword. shouldn't it be the payload ? navigation has to happen inside the observer's success function. pls post more complete code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem ist, that posting the content to an DB is an Async task. At the point where you are navigating to another path the callback function for the http post subscription has not been called yet. So at the point you navigate `this.isSaved` is undefined.

Try waiting until the callback function is executed. For example navigate in the callback function itself.

In my opinion there are to possible ways: `.post` returns an observable so you can return this observable in `updatePassword` and subscribe in the component.

Service:

```
public updatePassword(newPass: string) {
  // [...]
   return this.httpClient.post(this.URL_UPDATE_PASSWORD, { newPassword });
}
```

Component:

```
// [...]
this.Service.updatePassword(this.neuesPassword).subscribe((response) => {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/url',{ queryParams: { response: response } });
});
```

The better way in my opinion is converting the observable to an promise with `toPromise` then you can return this promise and resolve it in the component.

Service:

```
public updatePassword(newPass: string) {
    // [...]
    return this.httpClient.post(this.URL_UPDATE_PASSWORD, { newPassword }).toPromise();
}
```

Component:

```
// [...]
this.Service.updatePassword(this.neuesPassword).then((response) => {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/url',{ queryParams: { response: response } });
});
```

In both cases I would recommend reading about async await, promises and observables.

Comment: I think something like you say happens . But i dont understand how to solve it . can you give me some infos ? Thanks

Comment: I updated my solutions and tips where to search. Promises and Observables are a really important part of Angular especially when working with databases or other asynchronous tasks so I think it would help a lot getting into it.