# How to navigate to a component with input by Angular code

Tags: angular, navigation

I have a component that receives input by activating from another component I need to navigate from one component to another by code and send in the navigation the input value.
How do you do that?

I know how to navigate from one component to another but I do not know how to send it the input value.
I would appreciate your assistance!
Thanks.

this my 1 component:

```
 export class HostPersonalAreaComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }
  panelOpenState = false;
  @Input() suggestion: Suggestion;

  ngOnInit() {
  console.log(this.suggestion);
   }
}
```

This is the code that navigates to the component written above:

> ```
>     this.router.navigate(['/host-personal-area']);
> ```

The problem is that I did not send the input value. Does anyone know how to send?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add an so called **optional parameter** to your route.
In your first component you will need to add:

```
this.router.navigate(['/host-personal-area', {data: yourData}]);
```

This will result in a longer Url like `http://localhost:4200/host-personal-area;data=yourData`.

To read the data you need to add:

```
this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('data');
```

to your second component, so you can retrieve the parameter value that you added to your route before.
You could also have a look at [Send data through routing paths in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44864303/send-data-through-routing-paths-in-angular) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

Input are handy when a parent component communicates with its child. In your case, you want to rely on other patterns.

**Services**

A stateful service that holds the variable you want to use from one view to another can be the most reliable pattern you'd want to try.

Generate a service (using cli), and add a private behaviorSubject to it with its public accessors:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MySingletonService {
  private suggestion: BehaviorSubject<Suggestion> = new BehaviorSubject(null);

  onSuggestionChange(): Observable<Suggestion> {
    return this.suggestion.asObservable();
  }
  
  setSuggestion(nextSuggestion: Suggestion): void {
    this.suggestion.next(nextSuggestion);
  }
  
  resetSuggestion(): void {
    this.suggestion.next(null);
  }
}
```

You can then set the suggestion in your first component, trigger the navigation, and access it in the second one.

```js
export class MyFirstComponent {
  constructor(
    private myService: MyService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}
  
  setSuggestion(suggestion: Suggestion): void {
    this.myService.setSuggestion(suggestion);
    this.router.navigate(['to', 'second', 'component']);
  }
}

export class MySecondComponent {
  suggestion: Suggestion;
 
  constructor(private myService: MyService) {}
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myService.onSuggestionChange().subscribe(suggestion => this.suggestion = suggestion);
  }

}
```

**Query Params**

The second way to pass data is to use the url.
You can add parameters to your route by using the queryParams argument:

```
this.router.navigate(['url'], { queryParams: { suggestion }});
```

And then get in from the second component through ActivatedRoute:

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params) => { this.suggestion = params.get('suggestion');}
```