# Passing an object into Angular 9/10 resolver

Tags: angular, angular-resolver, angular-component-router

I am stuck with passing object to the resolver in Angular 9/10. Any help will be deeply appreciated.

I have a page `SearchUser.component.ts` from where I am navigating to another page `UserInfo.component.ts`. I am trying to pass the object in the resolver, which can execute my service with the user object model.

**A) SearchUser.component.ts**

```js
viewUser() {
    /*Data to be posted before the User info page is displayed*/
    let data = {
        "UserId": 1 "UserName": "David",
        "Department": "Physics"

    }

    /*STEP_1 Payload on the router*/
    const navigationExtra: NavigationExtras = { state: data };
    this.router.navigate(['Default/ApplicationDisplay', navigationExtra]);
}
```

**B) resolve-user.guards.ts**
( Here at Step 2 I am expecting the data which can be posted on the API) . But its showing null value.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree, Resolve, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { MyUserService } from '../services/my-user.service';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ResolveApplicationDetailsGuard implements Resolve < userList > {
    private postData: any;
    constructor(private _myUserService: MyUserService, private router: Router) {
        this.postData = router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state; //STEP_2 
    }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable < userList > | Promise < userList > | userList {
        return this._myUserService.GetUsersData(this.postData);
    }

}
```

**UserInfo.component.ts**

```js
getUserInfo() {
    //STEP_3
    this.activatedRoute.snapshot.data['userList'];
}
```

**app-routing.ts**

```js
path: 'UserInfo',
    component: UserInfoComponent,
    resolve: {
        userList: UserInfoGuard
    }
```

Appreciate if anyone can point me the right direction as certainly I am missing something.

Answer (score 2):

Am I reading it right - `let data` is not in the same scope (it is inside `viewUser` method) as `const navigationExtra`?

If `navigationExtra` is outsie the `viewUser`  method, you can not do this `{state:data}`, because data is not accessible in this scope. You have to assign `data` to a component's own property and then declare const `navigationExtra` like this:

```
navigationExtra: NavigationExtras = {state: this.data};
```

Comment: Thanks Aleks, Let me try your suggestion.

Comment: OK. Now I see, that I was mistaken - `data` and `navigationExtra` are in the same scope of a `viewUser` method..Tabing is just not proper. So my solutions probably won't fix the problem..

Answer (score 1):

You can follow these steps:

[Send data through routing paths in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44864303/send-data-through-routing-paths-in-angular)

I'm not sure but you can try to add data at the end of this line.

```
this.postData = router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.data;
```