# Angular routerLink to path

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I need to go to localhost:4200/route/SOME_PARAMETER where SOME_PARAMETER is a property of the component.

Currently I have this:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/route/${SOME_PARAMETER}']">
```

But it's taking me to an incorrect route.

I think I just need to  figure out the syntax.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send data through routing paths in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44864303/send-data-through-routing-paths-in-angular)

Answer (score 2):

Could you also provide your routing module?

Anyways,

in the routing module you would have following syntax:

`{ path: 'route/:id', component: SomeComponent}` (with or without "route", you got to know)

and the routerLink would look like that

`[routerLink]="'route/' + parameter"` (while "parameter" would be a global variable of the component.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is adding Dynamic Values to a routerLink.The syntax is the following, you can pass as many arguments as you want.

```
<a [routerLink]="['route',parameter]">
```

Of course you need to set up your routing module correctly. Considering your example it would be:

```
[{ path: 'route/:some_param', component: ComponentToBeRendered }]
```

From the official documentation:

> You can use dynamic values to generate the link. For a dynamic link, pass an array of path segments, followed by the params for each segment. For example, ['/team', teamId, 'user', userName, {details: true}] generates a link to /team/11/user/bob;details=true.

https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink