# How to send response from one component to another Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have this function and now I want to send the response of this function to paymentpage , Is there any way to pass it from function itself ..

```
itemsOnCart(event) {
        let myarray = [1 ,2, 3]
        const base_URL = 'http://localhost:9007/api/excel/getProductsId'
        this.http.post(base_URL, myarray).subscribe(r =>
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/paymentpage')
        )
      }
```

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54365098/715458

Comment: You can make this in several ways. Set myarray to localStorage and get it on /paymentpage if that is ok with you.