# How to retrieve queryParams passed to an Angular route via NavigateByUrl

Tags: angular, routes, query-string, angular-router-params

How to retrieve params passed as `NavigationExtras` using `navigateByUrl` as described below from the target component in Angular ?

```
let extras: NavigationExtras = {
                queryParams : {
                    errorTitle: 'Erreur Technique',
                    errorBody: 'URL erronée'
                }
            };
this.router.navigateByUrl(RoutesUrl.ERROR, extras);
```

Comment: There seems to be an existing bug I guess, details [here],(https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18798). Please go for `navigate` instead of `navigateByUrl` else you can try the alternate solutions in the github ticket if using navigate by url is absolutely necessary!

Comment: Thank you so much ! 
The solution suggested by Donsoulfresh worked fine for me ;)

Comment: The only inconvenience now is that all the data I pass as queryParams shows up in the address bar ! is there a way to hide it ?

Comment: you could use state instead, but when you refresh you will not have state persisting ` this.router.navigate(['action-selection'], { state: { example: 'bar' } });`, [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44864303/send-data-through-routing-paths-in-angular) answer with 349 points

Comment: I'm getting this `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'extras' of null` 
because of `this.router.getCurrentNavigation()` is returning `null`

Comment: found the solution !  `this.router.getCurrentNavigation()` must be called inside the constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I found is suggested by `soulfresh` in this GitHub issue : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18798

I call my route this way :

```
this.router.navigateByUrl(this.router.createUrlTree([RoutesUrl.ERROR], {
                queryParams: {
                    errorTitle: 'Erreur Technique',
                    errorBody: 'URL erronée'
                }
}));
```

then I retrieve query params this way :

```
this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap.subscribe(params => console.log(JSON.stringify(params)))
```

or

```
this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => console.log(JSON.stringify(params)))
```

### UPDATE

If you don't want that your `queryParams` appears in the address bar (URL) you can use :

Sending data :

```
constructor(private router: Router) {} 

ngOnInit(){
    this.router.navigate([RoutesUrl.ERROR], {
                    state: {
                        errorTitle: 'Erreur Technique',
                        errorBody: 'URL erronée'
                    }
    });
}
```

Retrieving data :

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
      this.errorTitle = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.errorTitle;
      this.errorBody = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.errorBody;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Activated Route` by injecting it into your component.

```
 constructor( private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute  ) {}

 ngOnInit(): void {
     this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params: Params) => {
        this.params = params;
    });
 }
```

Or you can get the queryParams from its activated routes' `snapshot`

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    const params = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams;
    console.log(params.errorTitle);
    console.log(params.errorBody);
}
```

Comment: Didn't work :( 
It returns `undefined`