# Not getting response from subscription

Tags: angular

I am trying to get a response from a subscription that I have. I can see that I get to the cart component fine but the subscription doesn't seem to be working and I don't see any errors either. Here is my code

*Service*

```
  @Output() event = new EventEmitter();
```

*Products component*

```
  addToCart(product): void {
    this._productsService.event.emit(product);   
  }

  goToCart(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['cart']);
  }
```

Cart component

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("gets here");
    this._productsService.event.subscribe(product => {
      console.log(product);
      let index = -1;
      index = this.cartProducts.findIndex(
        p => p.id === product.id
      );

        this.cartProducts.push(product);
      
      this.sum();
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Option 1: `ReplaySubject`

1. [`EventEmitter`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/13.2.6/packages/core/src/event_emitter.ts#L64) is a an Angular specific extension of RxJS `Subject`. As such, I'd say better to use it in conjunction with `@Output()` decorator b/n parent-child components as it is meant to be used.
2. Subscriptions to RxJS `Subject`, which you're indirectly using here, would only receive the emissions *after* the subscription. In your case, the event is emitted before the subscription.
3. Instead you could use RxJS [`ReplaySubject`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/ReplaySubject) with buffer 1 that would the last emitted value to future subscribers.

Service

```js
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';

private eventSource = new ReplaySubject(1);
public event$ = this.eventSource.asObservable();

public setEvent(value) {
  this.eventSource.next(value);
}
```

Products component

```js
addToCart(product): void {
  this._productsService.setEvent(product);   
}

goToCart(): void {
  this.router.navigate(['cart']);
}
```

Cart component

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this._productsService.event$.subscribe(product => {
    ...
  });
}
```

#### Option 2: Router params

Given that your components are related through Angular Router, you could use routing parameters to send data b/n them. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44865817/6513921) for more info.