# Router getCurrentNavigation always returns null only after upgrading to angular 15

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router, router

this problem appeared only after upgrading to angular 15,
I am passing a state property to the router but this.router.getCurrentNavigation() is returning a null value, that has been passed by `router.navigate` in another component

component A:

[image]

component B:

[image]

i can acsess state in compoment B using `this.state = history.state;` but `this.state = this.router.getCurrentNavigation()?.extras?.state ?? {};` dos not work,
it says that getCurrentNavigation() returns null. whay is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We had the same issue when we upgraded to Angular 15. We resolved it by adding a new resolver. This resolver can access the current route using getCurrentNavigation() and therefore can return the "extra" data back to the component.

```
@Injectable()
export class MyComponentResolver implements Resolve<MyComponentExtraData> {
  constructor(private router: Router) {
  }

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): MyComponentExtraData{
  
    return this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras?.state['MyData'];
  }
}
```

Then you can access the data returned by the resolver in the component constructor without any issue, using the activatedRoute.snapshot dictionary.

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
 
    let myData = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.data['myData'] /* the myData key depends on how you defined the resolver in your route declaration*/
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

Since Angular 15, `this.router.getCurrentNavigation()` might return null, because the component is instantiated after the navigation.

The alternative is to access the state from the Location (the one from `@angular/common`)

```
  import { Location } from '@angular/common';

  constructor(private location: Location) {
    location.getState() // do what you want 
  }
```