# Angular routing child route not appending to url

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular-router

I am using Angular routing and am wrapping all my components and routes in a parent path (as I want a dynamic base url path.)

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':basePath',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: OrderPageComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: '', component: DetailsComponent,
          },
          {
            path: 'category/:cat',
            component: CategoryComponent,
            data: {
              breadcrumb: ':cat'
            },
          },
          {
            path: 'category/:cat/:id',
            component: ItemComponent,
          }
        ]
      },
      { path: 'cart', component: CartComponent },
]
  }
];
```

edit - adding html for cart:

```
<a routerLink="/cart" class="cart" ActivatedRoute>cart</a>
```

&

```
<a routerLink="cart" class="cart" ActivatedRoute>cart</a>
```

the problem I am having is when I click on a child route (cart for example), the whole path is replaced with cart instead of appending.

What I want: `www.example.com/id-1/cart`
What I get: `www.example.com/cart`

This happens for all routes. How can I get around this?

Thank you

Comment: id-1 is a dynamic value? In case You want to append cart, It should be the child of that id-1 component

Comment: Do you really want `www.example.com/id-1/cart` or `www.example.com/cart/id-1/`? If you want to achieve the second, just change the order in your router. `category/:cat/:id` should be before `category/:cat`

Comment: @Simon yes it is definitely `www.example.com/id-1/cart` that I need, I have not managed to get this working anywhere

Comment: Can you share the code that generates the link to the cart?

Comment: @CharmisVarghese, I have edited my post to include the html for cart. 
Thanks

Comment: @DevStacker which components have these two `<a>` elements?

Comment: @CharmisVarghese Is it in the `HeaderComponent`

Comment: @DevStacker I think the issue is with the routerLink value. Can you take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38212529/relative-links-partial-routes-with-routerlink